# mysql stored procedures with error messages

Tags: mysql

I'm having some with registerusers stored procedure with error message and when I executed the result I got an error that says:' MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near /*declaring local variable*/
declare checkfirstnamecount int;
declare checklastn' at line 10'
```

Here's my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER go
Create procedure registerusers(
  Out UserID tinyint(11),
 IN iFirstName varchar(30),
 IN iLastName varchar(30),
 IN iPassword varchar(30),
 IN iEmailAddress varchar(30),
 IN iSalt varchar(40),
 IN iRoleID varchar(1))
BEGIN
/*declaring local variable*/
declare checkfirstnamecount int;
declare checklastnamecount int;
declare checkpasswordcount int;
delcare checksaltcount int;
declare checkroleidcount int;
declare checkemailcount int;

declare checkexistingemailaddress varchar(30);

/*checking the email address for one count*/
select count(emailaddress) into checkemailcount
from users
where emailaddress = iEmailaddress;

/*checking the password for one count*/
select count(Password) into checkpasswordcount
from users
where Password = iPassword;
/*checking the email address for one count*/
select count(FirstName) into checkfirstnamecount
from users
where FirstName = iFirstName;
/*checking the last name for one count*/
select count(LastName) into checklastnamecount
from users
where LastName = iLastName;
/*checking the salt for one count*/
select count(salt) into checksaltcount
from users
where salt = iSalt;
/*checking the roleid for one count*/
select count(RoleID) into checkroleidcount
from users
where RoleID = iRoleID;
/*checking the email address for one count for if it exists*/
select emailaddress into checkexistingemailaddress
from users
where emailaddress = iEmailaddress;

/*checking for firstname if the user forgot to fill out the first name*/
If(checkfirstnamecount!=1) then

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';
/*checking for Lastname  if the user forgot to fill out the last name*/
Elseif(checklastnamecount!=1) then

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the Last Name';
```

/*check if the password is not fill out*/
    Elseif(checkpasswordcount!=1) then

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the password';
```

/*check is the salt is not fill out*/
    Elseif(checksaltcount!=1) then

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Salt is not found';
/*check if the roleid is not fill out*/
Elseif(checkroleidcount!=1) then

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'RoleID is not found';

Elseif(checkemailcount!=1) then

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the email address';
/*checking if the emailaddress already exists in the table*/
Elseif(iEmailaddress=checkexistingemailaddress ) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Email Address already exists';

Else

insert into users(

FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
 )
Values
(
FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
);
set UserID = last_insert_id();  
 end if;

End
go
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: RTFM: [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html) `In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character`

Comment: @MarcB, MySQL's treatment of the `--` comment prefix is not like some other RDBMS implementations, which do not require a space follow. It's rude to say "RTFM" to someone who is *actually using the language correctly.*